# SQL Server - Dates, Greater than and Less than

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this stored procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[GetCarsByDates]
       (@startDate date, @returnDate date) 
as
    SELECT
        ManufacturerName, ModelName,
        CreationYear,
        Gear, CurrentKM,
        Picture,
        DATEDIFF(D, @startDate, @returnDate) * PricePerDay AS [Totalprice],
        PricePerDay, PricePerDayDelayed,
        InventoryCars.LicensePlate
    FROM 
        Models
    JOIN 
        Manufacturers ON Models.ManufacturerID = Manufacturers.ManufacturerID
    JOIN 
        InventoryCars ON InventoryCars.ModelID = Models.ModelID
    JOIN 
        CarsForRent ON CarsForRent.LicensePlate = InventoryCars.LicensePlate
    WHERE 
        CarsForRent.RentalStartDate < @startDate
        AND CarsForRent.RentalReturnDate < @returnDate
        AND CarsForRent.RentalReturnDate < @startDate
    ORDER BY 
        ManufacturerName, ModelName
```

I want to be able to select the properties by start and return dates. User inputs start date must be greater than return date and that is exactly what I did, but it still not working properly.

The problem is that I get rows results of items that are not available.

What is the problem with my where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your query should be written like below.
I assumed that you need to query all cars available from `startDate` to `returnDate` and need to check based on `CarsForRent`  table's columns 
`CarsForRent.RentalStartDate` and `CarsForRent.RentalReturnDate`

```
create procedure [dbo].[GetCarsByDates]@startDate date, @returnDate date
 as
BEGIN
    select DISTINCT ManufacturerName, ModelName, 
           CreationYear,Gear, CurrentKM, 
            Picture,
            DATEDIFF(D, @startDate, @returnDate)*PricePerDay as[Totalprice],
            PricePerDay,PricePerDayDelayed, InventoryCars.LicensePlate
     from Models 
         join Manufacturers  on Models.ManufacturerID=Manufacturers.ManufacturerID
         join InventoryCars  on InventoryCars.ModelID=Models.ModelID
         join CarsForRent    on CarsForRent.LicensePlate=InventoryCars.LicensePlate

 where 
   @startDate > CarsForRent.RentalReturnDate AND 
   CarsForRent.RentalReturnDate >CarsForRent.RentalStartDate 
   AND @startDate<=@returnDate
     order by ManufacturerName, ModelName  
 END
```

if you do not need to check that `returndate` is >`startdate`  remove this line from `where` clause :

```
AND @startDate<=@returnDate
```

I've created a sample fiddle
Please add values to it in left side and play with the use cases
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00236/1

Comment: this was just upvoted, that makes me wonder, which version of sqlserver is that BETWEEN syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the user only set startdate to values greater than returndate, you do this with an IF-Block before the actual query. For example so:

```
create procedure [dbo].[GetCarsByDates](@startDate date, @returnDate date) 
as
if @startDate <= @returnDate OR @startDate IS NULL OR @returnDate IS NULL
  BEGIN
   /* maybe do some stuff here */
   RAISERROR 'Errormessage', 11,1´;
   RETURN;
  END

/* here Comes your query without having to check the correctnes of the input-values */
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like that as i have understood from your question

```
where 
(@startDate > @returnDate) and RentalReturnDate < @startDate
```